# How do I connect to a SQL Server database using WebMatrix?

Tags: sql-server, webmatrix

I added a connection and it shows up in "Other Connections" but I can't seem to reference it.

```
var db = Database.Open("MyNewConnection");
```

throws an exception: `Connection string 'MyNewConnection' was not found.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure your connection string is correct in your web.config file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
   <add 
     name="MyNewConnection" 
     connectionString= "server=myServer;database=myDatabase;uid=username;pwd=password"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Oddly, I don't see that it created a web.config file.  In fact, I don't see my "Other Connections" persisted anywhere.

Comment: I believe `Database.Open` looks for either (1) a .sdf file in the website's App_Data folder or (2) a connection string in web.config. See: [Working with Data - Connecting to a Database](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/5-working-with-data#SB_ConnectingToADatabase)

Comment: "Other Connections" is listed on the left-pane upon clicking "Databases" tab on the bottom left of WebMatrix.