# How to check database values from view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Index.cshtml view on this view I have written getdate() function to returning some json data to another action of controller, here I have used one css class to display the date of the calendar. I want to add some css styling to this class after checking the the values in the database, how can I access to the database values from the Index.cshtml view.

Comment: Put in some source code. What DB are you using?

Comment: I am storing a date in the database with its unique id and if any particular value present in the database as here is date then I want to add css styling to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("NameOfYourDatabase");
    var select = "SELECT * FROM dates WHERE id = 1";
    var data = db.query(select);
}
```

The SQL select command depends on the structure of your DB.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737945/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-using-webmatrix) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744595/razor-c-sharp-get-data-from-database) question solve pretty the same problem.